# Google Login in flutter idToken = null

Tags: flutter, google-signin

When i login with google using sign_in_button package in flutter without using firebase, i get username, email, accessToken but the idToken = null. I can understand why idToken is returning null.
I have already registered Android OAuth ClientId in console.cloud.google.com and OAuth consent screen

I was trying to get idToken after logging in from google so that i can send the token to nodeJs backend to verify it. But instead of returning idToken I got null as idToken

**My Code**

```
const List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
];

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  // Optional clientId
  scopes: scopes,
);
```

for pressing login button for google login:

```
onPressed: () async {
 GoogleSignInAccount? googlUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
await googlUser!.authentication;
print(
idToken = ${googleSignInAuthentication.idToken} user detail = ${googlUser.email} accessToken = ${googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken}");
```

Comment: Add profile scope for sign-in